# Custom script type in HTML document

Tags: javascript, html

I am implementing a 3rd party widget and was given the following script:

```html
<script type="acme/widget">
  {
    "some": "value" | "siteId": "hotel" | "money" | "travel"
  }
</script>
```

Notice the custom script type `acme/widget`?
Browser console is complaining because the JavaScript interpreter tries to parse the illegal contents.

```text
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token | in JSON at position 30
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at p (app.js:1)
```

How can I make this custom script load on my page without errors? Is there a way to register a custom script type?

Comment: I suppose if all else fails you could load it into some other element and hide that element, and have your widget read it from there.

Comment: *"Browser console is complaining because the JavaScript interpreter tries to parse the illegal contents."* It shouldn't be. The script is clearly identified as **not** JavaScript. What browser?

Comment: The code in the question does not replicate the problem. I've taken your `scirpt` tag and put it in a Stack Snippet. Running it does not cause any error -- which is correct, because the `script` is not processed as JavaScript, since it has a different `type`.

Comment: Google Chrome browser. Latest.
I can't give you the link (internal corporate) but the same script is running fine in the same browser, just on a different production website. So clearly there is a way make the document load using a custom script type, but how?

Comment: @ChrisRich - The code in the question does not cause that problem in Chrome (or Firefox, or any other vaguely-standards-compliant browser). Normally when libs/widgets do this, they have code loaded separately that looks for `script` elements with the given `type` and does something with them. So the question is: What is this `p` function that's trying to use `JSON.parse` on something that isn't JSON?

Comment: Also who is the brainiac that uses something almost but not quite JSON to be read by JS

Answer (score 1):

HTML LS as of 2022-02-20 [states](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-type):

> The **`type`** attribute allows customization of the type of script represented:
>
> - […]
> - Setting the attribute to any other value [than a JS MIME type or `"module"`] means that the script is a **data block**, which is not processed. None of the `script` attributes (except `type` itself) have any effect on data blocks. Authors must use a valid MIME type string that is not a JavaScript MIME type essence match to denote data blocks.

Which means that a script element with a type that is neither `"module"` nor a JavaScript MIME type ought to be ignored by the browser entirely.  The stack trace in the question clearly comes from attempting to invoke `JSON.parse` on the contents of the element from within a script named ‘app.js’, which of course fails, because the contents are not valid JSON.

The only way to register your own script type is to have a script that finds all data block elements in the DOM, and then uses `MutationObserver` to catch any that are added afterwards.  An example of doing just that can be found in [Fengari, a JavaScript implementation of Lua](https://github.com/fengari-lua/fengari-web/blob/77d35f5e1516f431cbb96e165b4272f2fc9b0b3a/src/fengari-web.js#L202-L294).